# How to create setup file for blackberry using phonegap?

Tags: blackberry, cordova

I developed blackberry app using phonegap.

With the help of command prompt,
I build the project with BlackBerry Code signing key,then it can successfully build 
and gives the OTAInstall folder contains cod and jad file.

But my client wants to only one jad file to install their device.

Actually I tried to install the jad file without cod file, at that time the device shown error.

So, Everytime I install the app to my device, I used the OTAInstall folder containing the cod and jad file.

How can I convert this lot of files into one single file?

Answer (score 1):

Only one jad file won't install the application. Anyway you need either jad file + cod file(s), or alx file + cod file(s).

jad file + cod stands for OTA install via browser

alx file + cod stands for desktop computer installation via BB Desktop Manager and usb-cable, attached to BB Device.

There's a workaround, it works only for desktop installation and it has a side effect.

Your application won't be listed under `Applications list` in device options.

You can use javaloader.exe utility that loads and erases cod files on attached BB device. This utility can be found in JDE (Java Development Environment) `bin` folder.

So, create bat-file that invokes javaloader and loads cod-files to connected device. And pack it along with your cod file(s) in SFX-archive, that runs that bat file when archive has been unpacked.